# Умерла батарея на маке. Перешел в постоянный режим пониженного потребления

Tags: macos, macbook

Умерла батарея на Macbook Air. Постоянно пишет заряд 1%. Пока жду новый аккумулятор, хотелось бы комфортно работать.
Но не получается, т.к. мак перешел в режим низкой мощности (обычно когда зарядка становится меньше 5%).

Как только не пробовал, не выходит он из этого режима.
Может кто-то сталкивался и решал этот вопрос?

Comment: Батарея не заряжается. Всегда пишет 1% зарядки. И всегда мак в режиме низкого потребления, проц еле работает.

Comment: дак снимите батарею вообще. работайте с провода. или он так не умеет?

Comment: конечно не умеет

Comment: @teran это же мак. Там у них свой мир, иногда нелогичный и беспощадный.

Comment: Ноут, который не работает от розетки при севшей батарее это что-то запредельно-прекрасное. :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 зачем нести чушь? батарея не севшая, а конченая, разбухшая. И получился такой глюк, что мак постоянно видит заряд батареи 1%. Надо батарею просто менять вовремя, а я мучал ее еще в течение полугода. Вот и результат

Comment: У меня была разбухшая батарея, макбук её не видел и работал и с ней и без неё, попробуйте её отключить, если всё равно собираетесь менять.